# VS2015 Pointers keep changing, alignment?

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2015, kernel, alignment

Working in Visual Studio 2015, on a kernel driver project. I have noticed this sort of thing is happening;

```
dprintf("os %p; os_lock %p\n", os, &os->os_lock);
mutex_init(&os->os_lock);
mutex_enter(&os->os_lock);

void mutex_init(kmutex_t *mp) {
  dprintf("%s is %p\n", __func__, mp);
  ...

void mutex_enter(kmutex_t *mp) {
  dprintf("%s is %p\n", __func__, mp);
  ...

os 0xffffa08b29041ac0; os_lock 0xffffa08b29041df8
mutex_init is 0xffffa08b29041df8
mutex_enter is 0xffffa08b29041df0  <---
```

So what happened there? Sure, it's an alignment thing that VS2015 is doing for some reason, but it's extra confusing since the first call is correct, then it decides to mess it up in the 2nd. That just seems like a really bad thing.  The struct is made with alignment in mind, and `os_lock` is +0x338 in.

I can throw `#pragma pack(8)` around that struct to stop it, but it seems to happen in quite a few other places, and it needs to stop :) I can't imagine VS2015 would be this random, so it must be something I manage to do.

Answer (score 0):

Hah, the world is sane again. Turns out one of the header files had `#pragma pack(4)` to make userland struct passed into kernel be the same, but header file ended with `#pragma push()` - not sure what the brain was doing there, but git commit was at 1am.

So, depending on which files included said header, and which did not, pack was either 4 or 8. Sure made things interesting.  Lets put this down to PEBCAK people, sorry for the noise.